# Is there a way to pull a contact list without intents? Then save them in a file?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Basically I was wondering *if* its possible to store all contact data in a file or listview without opening the intent. Essentially making my own contact screen within my app.

In the event that this is possible, could someone point me in the direction of a post that goes over how to save and pull data from a file?

Comment: Why would you *want* to "store all contact data in a file"? You would be forever out of sync. "in a file or listview" -- these two concepts have nothing to do with each other, on any operating system. "without opening the intent" -- without opening what `Intent`? "how to save and pull data from a file" -- what file?

Comment: Who sonny no need to be so hostile. The reason I want to store my contact information in a file is irrelevant.

What I meant to say is that rather than opening the contact list intent (the native contact browser), I would like to create my own.

The reason I mentioned the file, is so I could do inputstream and outputstream to store contacts then pull them into an array to populate a listview.

Sorry for the vagueness, I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: People will be more likely to be "hostile" to you if you refer to them as "sonny". That being said, I don't know who downvoted you.

Comment: You're probably right, but your argument doesn't hold up considering I said that after the fact. Regardless, these two comments are irrelevant.. This isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the contact data using a [Content Provider (Android Developers)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Read the example below the heading *"Querying a Content Provider"*.

For reading and writing data to a file you can use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. You find an example of how to use them in [this post](http://www.anddev.org/write_to_and_read_from_a_file-t3173.html).